# What parameters do I change to train a pytorch model from scratch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I followed this tutorial to train a pytorch model for instance segmentation:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

I would not like to train a model on entirely different data and classes, totally unrelated to COCO. What changes do I need to make to retrain the model. From my reading I'm guessing besides have the correct number of classes I just need to train this line:

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
```

to

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False)
```

But I notice there is another parameters: `pretrained_backbone=True, trainable_backbone_layers=None` should they be changed too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function signature is

> `torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False, progress=True, num_classes=91, pretrained_backbone=True, trainable_backbone_layers=3, **kwargs)`

Setting `pretrained=False` will tell PyTorch not to download model pre-trained on COCO train2017. You want it as you're interested in training.

Usually, this is enough if you want to train on a different dataset.

When you set `pretrained=False`, PyTorch will download pretrained ResNet50 on ImageNet. And by default, it'll freeze first two blocks named `conv1` and `layer1`. This is how it was done in Faster R-CNN paper which frooze the initial layers of pretrained backbone.

(Just print model to check its structure).

```
layers_to_train = ['layer4', 'layer3', 'layer2', 'layer1', 'conv1'][:trainable_layers]
```

Now, if you don't even want the first two layers to freeze, you can set `trainable_backbone_layers=5` (done automatically, when you set `pretrained_backbone=False`), which will train the entire resnet backbone from scratch.

Check [PR#2160](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/2160).

Answer (score 1):

From `maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn` [document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#mask-r-cnn):

- pretrained (bool) – If True, returns a model pre-trained on COCO train2017
- pretrained_backbone (bool) – If True, returns a model with backbone pre-trained on Imagenet
- trainable_backbone_layers (int) – number of trainable (not frozen) resnet layers starting from final block. Valid values are between 0 and 5, with 5 meaning all backbone layers are trainable.

So for training from scratch using:

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False, pretrained_backbone=False, trainable_backbone_layers=5, num_classes=your_num_classes)
```

or:

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=False, pretrained_backbone=False, num_classes=your_num_classes)
```

because in source code of [maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/detection/mask_rcnn.html#maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn):

```
if not (pretrained or pretrained_backbone):
    trainable_backbone_layers = 5
```